# What is a good strategy for defeating groups of Galvanades?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I just entered Costlemark Tower (recommended level 55) with a level 56 Noctis, 53 Gladiolus and Ignis, and 52 Prompto, thinking I'd be okay.

However, as soon as I got to the second encounter, I very quickly realized that I will not be okay.

This dungeon is chock full of [Galvanades](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Galvanade), which

- cut your max HP down while you fight them
- constantly explode
- summon 3 more Thunderbombs at a time when they explode.

Despite them being roughly on par with my party in terms of level (54), they absolutely destroy my party.

This last encounter I was stuck in had me against 3-4 Galvanades, but very quickly turned into a fight against those 3-4 Galvanades, plus about 20-30 Thunderbombs, which made it very hard to see (and live). My experience looked a bit like [this video](https://youtu.be/M0yeWNk6twk). (Language warning on the title)

Is there some secret to beating them that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have completed this dungeon and these enemies prompted me to have a search around.

The technique I used was to cook up some Dual-Cast or better Blizzara, to open the fight with and then to use Gladio's abilities, either Cyclone or Dawn Hammer, which will cause them to flinch.

Then it's a matter of prioritising them as quick as you can, if you have Tech Bar boosting items, you can use Ignis' Overwhelm ability. If you can kill or stagger them, they won't explode, thus not spawning the additional mobs.

[Gamersheroes recommends](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/final-fantasy-15-dungeon-guide-castlemark-tower/),

> Galvanade (Level 54) Weaknesses: Royal Arms, Guns, Machine Weapons,
>   Blizzard
>   Notes: If you take too long to kill these they summon lots of
>   Thunder Bombs. Dawn Hammer works to take them down quick.

Other [techniques people have used](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74663791), also work with your bros abilities.

> Promto+graviton shot+killcast 99 blizzara=gg move on.

Also worth cooking a meal which helps with elemental resistance.

> .. the meal you can get at Galdin Quay that negates elemental attacks - crab something or other. Costs about 3000 gil

Comment: My strategy was "do as much damage to them as fast as possible". but I was in my 70's when i tackled this dungeon. Even at 99, these enemies are problematic if not killed quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was too far into the dungeon to justify leaving to get that meal (though it would have undoubtedly helped tremendously), but this is very good advice. My strategy pretty much revolved around keeping Gladio alive so I could spam Dawnhammer as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I skipped them except the part where you had to kill them to proceed. I used Armiger during the one where you have to crouch under some rubble and then when I was at the puzzle room it spawned 3 of those and a yojimbo and I didnt have any Armiger left so I ended up using some mega-phoenix and I kept spamming techs and somehow I survived